# Gparted, Gedit doesn't open with the gksu command [Xubuntu]

Tags: xubuntu, gparted, gedit, gksu

I'm not able to start software as GParted, GEdit with the gksu command (neither the sudo). I see commands in the task manager start, but disappear before to have a result.
So, have you any clue to solve this ?

Also I'm quite new on Linux (not totally). So please, could you be specific ?
Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: What version of Xubuntu are you using?  As gksudo is considered a security risk it was dropped by Xubuntu in the current trough between LTS releases.  The online documentation shipped with Xubuntu discusses the use of pkexec instead.  I'll draft an answer properly when not in bed...

Comment: I use the 14.04.2 LTS.
I solved my issue by install it again. Now it work perfectly (I'm able to launch gparted from the graphical menu). I don't know what was wrong.

Like said on of my coding teacher : a cosmic ray

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to see if ROOT is the owner of your configuration file (this can happen when you use 'sudo' instead of 'gksudo' in launching app with a GUI).

> find $HOME -not -user $USER -exec ls -lad {} \;

In this case use:

> sudo chown -R %YOUR_USERNAME%:%YOUR_USERNAME% %TARGET_FILE_OR_DIRECTORY%

to change configuration files' owner.

Cheers

Comment: Well, I have no response
If i well understand the command it ask something like : "Find all file in home were the user is not the owner and display they attributes".
I don't think then I have such files.